# CodeIgniter 3 + SQL Server + Windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I have a project working with CodeIgniter and sqlserver 2008 I updated my pc to windows 10 then stopped working, the sqlserver driver for php is configured and my php ini shows it, also the code connects to sql server but now when im triying to do a query it givme false
so this code:

```
 $this->db->select('*')->from('distritos')->get()->result();
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\
```

Always its like sqlserver not working anymore but cannot fix it.

Php info shows

```
PDO

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, pgsql, sqlite, sqlsrv

pdo_sqlsrv

pdo_sqlsrv support  enabled
Version 3.0.2.2R (Unofficial)
Unofficial Changes  Works with Native Clients 11/10/9

sqlsrv

sqlsrv support  enabled
Version 3.0.2.2R (Unofficial)
Unofficial Changes  Works with Native Clients 11/10/9
```

EDIT:
its my mistake cannot conect

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:/www/***/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 436
```

the database config its okay :S

Comment: Connect ok? dump of `$this->db->get('distritos')->result()` ?

Comment: yes connect ok, that give me the same error Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C: 
the dump of $this->db->get('dis‌​tritos') give me "false".
Also tried oficial drivers 

EDIT: My mistake not connecting :S

Comment: Do you set 'database' in autoload.php (`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database')`) ?

Comment: Already fixed, database password expired xd, What should i do ? delete the question ?

Comment: Answer by yourself, declare the mistake, provide the solution and accept the answer for yourself. Better if you give some tips. Maybe would help other later.

Comment: done, thanks for fast response

Comment: Yes delete it. Only keep questions you think would help someone else.

Comment: This may help someone else to debug

Answer (score 0):

The error wasnt on the config, was on the password that was expired but the code igniter wasn't showing the error becouse i have to active this config :

database.php

```
'db_debug' => TRUE,
```

Solved ;)